# Determining what is causing so much sys time in my userspace bound executable on Linux

Tags: linux, time, profiling, system

I'm working on a project (programming language) and I'm starting to do some profiling. When I run time on my factorial test, I get the following:

```
burton@smokey:~/repl$ time tests/fact.repl 

real    0m4.451s
user    0m1.820s
sys     0m2.620s
```

My problem is with the sys time.  I am doing no system calls other than reading the input files (there is no output).   This should be an almost completely user time bound application.  I have tried running strace -c to see if there are any errant system calls taking up a lot of time but have found nothing.  Gprof doesn't give me any answers either.

Are there any other tools to find out what is taking so much system time in my application?  Am I just being tricked by the time command?  When I run sbcl doing the same calculation, the sys time is around 0.03 seconds and what I am hoping for.

Here is the complete output of strace -c:

```
burton@smokey:~/repl$ strace -c tests/fact.repl
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  -nan    0.000000           0         2           read
  -nan    0.000000           0         3           open
  -nan    0.000000           0         2           close
  -nan    0.000000           0         3           fstat
  -nan    0.000000           0        12           mmap
  -nan    0.000000           0         4           mprotect
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           munmap
  -nan    0.000000           0        16           brk
  -nan    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  -nan    0.000000           0         4           rt_sigprocmask
  -nan    0.000000           0         1         1 ioctl
  -nan    0.000000           0         3         3 access
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           execve
  -nan    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  -nan    0.000000           0         2           setrlimit
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 100.00    0.000000                    57         4 total
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time it takes to allocate and page in your memory counts as system time. Try `/usr/bin/time tests/fact.repl` -- it shows the number of page faults.

By the way, "I am doing no system calls other than reading the input files" and "I am allocating gobs of memory" are contradictory statements.

Comment: Gobs meaning large chunks at one time (256MB) using sbrk.  The actual time of sbrk was very low for every call.  So is there hidden system time after sbrk is called to actually allocate the memory that's being requested?

Comment: I might add that I wasn't allocating over my system memory and hitting swap either, although it was allocating quite a bit (multiple GB on an 8GB machine).

Comment: Page faulting several GB of memory is going to take some time. Normally on x86 page size is 4k, so every 4k of memory you touch for the first time makes a page fault. I think the kernel zeros memory before giving it to you.

Comment: Yes, there is a hidden cost after `sbrk`. Only when you actually touch the allocated virtual memory is physical memory assigned to it. That assignment can be expensive, and is accounted for as system time.

Answer (score 1):

> I am doing no system calls

That seems unlikely given what `time` prints.

First, run your program under `strace -c`. This will tell you how many system calls you've executed, and which ones of them took most time.

Once you know the "interesting" system calls, you can obtain additional details with `strace -tt -T -e trace=<interesting syscall>`. See [strace man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) for more info.

Since `strace -c` shows (effectively) 0 time, perhaps you are forking subprocesses or creating threads? In that case, `strace -f` might give interesting output.

Comment: From the OP: "I am doing no system calls *other than reading the input files* [...]". +1 for methods of pinning down where to optimize.

Comment: I have run it under strace -c; each %time comes out as -nan, I have a total of 57 calls, none of which seem to be adding anything to the total execution time (hence the -nan I am assuming). My final strace -c line gives a grand total of 0.00000 seconds for all of the system calls.

Comment: Please update your question with complete output of `strace -c`

Comment: Nor forking, no subprocesses.  Just reading the input file, compiling to internal bytecode and executing a mathematical calcuation.  Not even printing the result (which is big).

Comment: Do cache misses or TLB misses count as sys time?  I am allocating gobs of memory (wrote my own malloc using sbrk and incrementing a pointer).  Could that be the cause of the increased system time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any clues, but is your program using several threads and Posix synchronisation primitives (e.g. `pthread_mutex_lock` etc...)? Because these primitives are built on some system calls (the futex ones).